# I am using jQuery to hide/display values based on specific classes but need help confining the function to specific scopes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a web page to describe how to use index/match formulas in excel.

I am creating a table where you can toggle between an Excel formula and the result. It looks something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="selectformula">Show Formulas</input> | <input type="checkbox" class="selectvalue">Show Values</input>

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
<tr><td>Atlas</td><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>Campaign Name</td><td>Publisher Name</td><td> Impressions</td><td>Clicks</td><td>Mapped Impressions</td><td>Mapped Clicks</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td><td>Campaign A</td><td>Publisher A</td><td>100</td><td>10</td><td><span class="formula">=INDEX(DCM!C:C,MATCH(B2,DCM!B:B,0))</span><span class="value">90</span></td><td><span class="formula">=INDEX(DCM!D:D,MATCH(B2,DCM!B:B,0))</span><span class="value">5</span></td></tr>
 <tr><td>3</td><td>Campaign A</td><td>Publisher B</td><td>200</td><td>20</td><td><span class="formula">=INDEX(DCM!C:C,MATCH(B3,DCM!B:B,0))</span><span class="value">175</span></td><td><span class="formula">=INDEX(DCM!D:D,MATCH(B3,DCM!B:B,0))</span><span class="value">25</span></td></tr>
 <tr><td>4</td><td>Campaign B</td><td>Publisher A</td><td>500</td><td>50</td><td><span class="red"><span class="formula">=INDEX(DCM!C:C,MATCH(B4,DCM!B:B,0))</span><span class="value">90</span></span></td><td><span class="red"><span class="formula">=INDEX(DCM!D:D,MATCH(B4,DCM!B:B,0))</span><span class="value">5</span></span></td></tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".value").hide();
  $('.selectformula, .selectvalue').change(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("checked", false);
    if($('.selectformula').is(':checked')){
      $('.selectvalue').prop('checked', false);
      $('.formula').show();
      $('.value').hide();
    }
    if ($('.selectvalue').is(':checked')){
      $('.selectformula').prop('checked', false);
      $('.value').show();
      $('.formula').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Basically, within a td in my table I have a span for the formula and value. I hide the value initially and display the formula. When the "show value" checkbox is selected, I hide the formula and show the value.

The problem is, I have multiple tables on the same page that use the same classes, so if I select "show values" for one table, all other tables on the page show the value as well which I want to avoid.

Is there a way I can possibly wrap the checkboxes and tables in a div and only influence the results in that particular div even if there are other elements on the page that share the same classes?

Ideally I would want to do something like:

1. User interacts with div (hovers, maybe?).
2. User selects a checkbox within the div.
3. Formula/values are toggled in table within that div based on checkbox selected.

I'm thinking I could give each div the same class name, and when it's hovered on and "this".checkbox is changed, I could execute the rest of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `change` event's `this` will be the checkbox that was selected,.  So all you need to do is make a reference to the containing table.  You can do this using closest.

eg.

```
var $table = $(this).closest("table");
```

Now instead of just doing something like -> `$('input[type="checkbox"]').xxxxx` change that that to ->

```
$table.find('input[type="checkbox"]').xxxxx
```

Basically `$table` is now scoped to just the current table, and not the whole document..

Comment: Thank you! You and dave had the same idea. 

My code works closer than before but I'm still experiencing some weird behavior.

https://jsfiddle.net/ebu8apbb

If I select "show values" in each checkbox it works, but if I select "show formulas" from the top it wont let me select "show values" from the bottom. Any idea why?

Comment: You have not used your `$isolate` everywhere in the function, soon as you do something like `$(selector)` your back at looking at the whole DOM.  Here it is fixed -> http://jsfiddle.net/ebu8apbb/4/   Also `<INPUT>` tags don't have a closing tag `</INPUT>` The fiddle even highlights these in red for you.

Comment: OH thank you!! It works perfectly now, and I learned something new :). Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.closest` to get the wrapper (lets call it `<div class="wrapper">`), then use that element in `$.find` to find the children you want:

```
$(this).closest('div.wrapper').find('.formula').show();
$(this).closest('div.wrapper').find('.value').hide();
```

Comment: Thank you! You and Keith had the same idea. 

My code works closer than before but I'm still experiencing some weird behavior. jsfiddle.net/ebu8apbb If I select "show values" in each checkbox it works, but if I select "show formulas" from the top it wont let me select "show values" from the bottom. Any idea why?